# Conditional loop based on current page

Tags: theme-development, loop, conditional-content

I'm trying to get the loop below to display only the post with the category that reflects the given condition but it doesn't seem to work. Any Ideas on how this can be achieved?

```
    <?php 
    if ( is_page('css-tutorial')); 
     global $x;
     $x = 'css';

    ?>
    <?php

    // assign the variable as current category
       $category = $x;

    // concatenate the query
      $args = 'category_name=' . $category;

            // run the query
      query_posts( $args );

    $query = new WP_Query('category_name=$x');

    if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 

    ?>
    <div class="multi-post">
      <div class="sizer">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail($size, $attr); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="exerper">
        <h2>
          <?php the_title(); ?>
        </h2>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <span class="linker"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_author(); ?>
        |
        <?php the_date(); ?>
        | &rarr; Continue </a></span><!-- End Upper Linker --> 

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End multi-post -->

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why are you using two functions for query? Try removing 'query_posts'.

Comment: in addition to the above, you've got some php errors, always develop with [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). read the php manual for correct use of [if / elseif](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php), and the difference between [single and double quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).